# How to use schedule with a async function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

When I try to schedule a function in Python that is async I get an error. that is how my code is written:

```
def Sheduling():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

async def Asyncfunction():
    #stuffs

ScheduleDaily= schedule.every().monday.do(Asyncfunction)
Thread = Thread(target=Sheduling, daemon=True)
Thread.start()
```

What I can do? I get that error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Asyncfunction' was never awaited
  self._run_job(job)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Comment: you need to `await` async functions to ultimately run them. your code does not do that anywhere. and looking at the docs it does not appear to take `async` functions to begin with [docs](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do)

Comment: What can I do? I tried addin a await in front but isn't working.

Comment: you can't. the `schedule` library does not support async functions if you look at the docs

Comment: What do you suggest me?

Comment: don’t make the function async? i don’t know what you want me to tell you

Comment: The problem is that I tried to make the function sync, but I get an error on a routine, since I have to get a list generated by a coroutine.